# What decides the structure of the dual variables taken in designing min-max type combinatorial optimization algorithms?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, integer-programming, duality-theorems, discrete-optimization

There are a bunch of combinatorial optimization problems like min cost flows and min weight perfect matchings that invoke duality and complimentary slackness to improve the primal feasible solution. However, it is usually remarked that they take to account only a 'particular type' of dual variables, for example in the Blossom Algorithm (http://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/CS369P-files/lec6.pdf), the dual variables 'uses only sets from some laminar family $\Omega$'.

Now my query is essentially equivalent to - why this family, moreover , why only this family. What suffices their use and what motivates their construction? Also as a follow up - Does it relate to total dual integrality and (if yes, then) how?

Comment: From my reading of the paper you've linked to, the fact that $\Omega$ is a "laminar family" is not some explicit, pre-ordained goal of their approach. Rather, it is a *consequence* of the algorithm and the structure of the problem they are solving. The reason it is important for them to identify the set as laminar is that it ensures that the cardinality of the set is $O(n)$, which guarantees that the complexity of their algorithm is polynomial. That is what is important: the fact that $|\Omega|$ is polynomial in $n$, not that it is laminar specifically.